# Where can I get more information about Owner?

Tags: soql, sobject, standard-objects, user

There were one time that I was trying to get the Owner name from Case. I searched online and knew that I can use the following query to achieve:

```
Select Id, AccountId, Owner.Name, Owner.Email, Owner.Username, Owner.title from Case
```

I would like to know that where's this Owner coming from? I don't see there's a Owner object and I believe that Owner.Name was getting from User object.  However, how do I know what other data I can retrieve by using Owner.xxx?

Thanks

Comment: Technically user object is the owner object. So any field that you have on a user object ( and accessible for a user) should be able ok to be queried. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So yes, typically Owner relates to the User obj, **BUT** it can also relate to the Group obj. There are a number of standard objects that have multiple Objects off Owner (kinda of like the WhatId or WhoId on task) for instance a Case can belong to a queue (Group) and so Owner.Email would be invalid. Task can also belong to a Queue (Group). If you look in the Schema browser, you can see what Objects owner ties to. You can also use the `OwnerId.getSobjectType()` to see what it ties to.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, totally forgot about groups!

Comment: :-) its the silent killer of all queries :-P i had an issue with it not to long ago off Owner. I thought i was going mad, and then realized it was because group didnt have email!

Answer (score 2):

Owner is basically the **relationship name** for a lookupfield to the User object. Many standard objects come with this.

As through any relationship, **you can query for all fields on the other side** up to a few levels of dept.

Answer (score 1):

Owner is User Object.You can view the list of fields through force.com explorer or schema builder in salesforce IDE(force.com plugin)